# Wide single CLB functions FPGA

Tags: fpga

Could someone explain to me what wide function means?

Is it a function with big number of inputs in single CLB or smth else?

EDIT 1

It is from  [virtex fpga xilinx](https://slideplayer.com/slide/12759613/), p18

EDIT 2

'planar non planar pipulation', p 35, What is "pipulation"

Comment: You need to provide more context. Show us a paragraph where this phrase is used, and be sure to cite the source.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson i added

Answer (score 0):

A "wide" function is a Boolean expression that has (relatively) many inputs. I have no idea about "pipulation". Perhaps it is a misspelling of "population" but I don't understand how they are using it in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this presentation is from last century (I guess 1999 to introduce the Virtex series), and many of the things shown there are now either common or outdated since a long time.

The "Wide Single CLB function" promoted on slide 18 is a feature that allows to interconnect the 4 LUTs in one CLB. They can provide up to 13 inputs used in parallel to generate one output signal without having to use routing to leave the CLB. As can be seen in the drawing, this is not the same as a LUT-13 that would be able to implement any logic function, but is rather limited in the functions it can implement.

"Pipulation" is a term coined by Xilinx:

> https://patents.google.com/patent/US6144220A/en 
> The term PIP stands for programmable interconnection point. The term
> pipulation stands for PIP population.

So, each configurable switch in a connection matrix is a PIP, and the more of these interconnection points are used (the denser the design is) the higher the pip-population or pipulation is. Planar and non-planar are explained on the slides: A planar interconnect is one that connects same type of routing resources with each other, and non-planar interconnect allows different types of resources to be connected. That is, long-range routing wires can be directly connected to short-range routing.

Comment: what is a number format Q 12.8? how to convert into this format ?